Find actual file by only file name, not literally everything non-related
PuTTY/SSH and logged in as root I simply want to find any instances of the file PEAR.php.
I've looked through a dozen different tutorials but they seem to just copy-paste the same instructions. An example of a command returns hundreds of files seemingly on the logic that because a file has characters from Earth that it must be a match:
 find -L / -name 'PEAR.php'

I don't want to match processes.
I don't want to substring search contents of files.
I don't want " is part of the same file system loop as ".

How do I have the terminal show the absolute paths of all instances of PEAR.php without all the completely non-related results?

(1) "is part of the same file system loop as" is a diagnostic message to stderr, not a result. Why do you think you need -L? When starting from /, your find is going to visit all files in the tree anyway. (2) "I don't want to substring search contents of files" – The command you posted shall not do this. What result (or "result") makes you think it does?

This question is similar to: How do I remove "permission denied" printout statements from the find program?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You might want to edit this to leave the question but remove the attitude. We didn't write whatever random "tutorial" you chose to read, so your anger and frustration are misdirected. The command you show, find, will only ever find things based on their name, not their content. You just need to limit the results to regular files as explained in the answer.

Don't use -L, as the documentation (see man find) writes,

if the -L option or the -follow option is  in  use,  a  diagnostic message  is  issued when find encounters a loop of symbolic links.

So your command could be this:
find / -name 'PEAR.php'

If you want to guarantee that PEAR.php is a regular file then tell find so:
find / -type f -name 'PEAR.php'

I don't understand why the remaining two criteria ("I don't want to match processes" and "I don't want to substring search contents of files") are an issue, because your find command wouldn't perform these anyway
One last thought. If you're running this on an OS such as a Linux-based one that uses filesystem space to expose kernel values you will iterate across those too. For example, /proc and /sys, and arguably even /dev, are pseudo-filesystems. You might want to exclude those from your search command:
find / \( -path '/proc' -o -path '/sys' -o -path '/dev' \) -prune -o -type f -name 'PEAR.php' -print

